# Which one is good approach to find the nth heighest salary

Tags: sql

For finding the nth heighest salary from a table, there are different ways:

suppose if I want find out 3rd heighest salary then

1)

```
select MIN(sal)
from ( select distinct top 3 sal from chksal order by sal desc) as a;
```

2)

```
select distinct sal 
from chksal x where 3=(select COUNT(distinct sal) from chksal y where x.sal<=y.sal);
```

3)

```
select distinct sal 
from chksal x where 2=(select COUNT(distinct sal) from chksal y where x.sal<y.sal);
```

4)

```
select top 1 sal  
from ( select distinct top 3 sal from chksal order by sal desc) result order by sal;
```

Up to my knowledge these are the ways.

Can anyone tell are there any other ways?

Which one is best to query according to performance

Comment: You can Use `rownumber()`

Comment: Whar rdbms are you using?

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . Based on the use of `top`, I would say either SQL Server or Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

To get nth highest value:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name DESC
LIMIT n - 1, 1
```

The query just returns the first row after n-1 rows so you get the nth highest record.

Comment: It's not clear what rdbms OP is using, but the cards are stacked against MySql because of his `TOP`-clause.

Answer (score 1):

To test for performance, you should try the various queries on your system with your data.   And, ify ou care about performance, you should learn about execution plans and learn how to read them.  If I had to guess, of these, the first and fourth would have better performance.

But.  For what you want to do, there is a built-in function called `dense_rank()`:

```
select top 1 salary
from (select cv.*, dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as r 
      from chkksal cv
     ) cv
where r = 3;
```

As a note.  This uses `top` without an `order by`.  Usually this is discouraged, but all the salaries where `r = 3` are the same, so it is ok in this case.

Also, `dense_rank()` is used because your queries have `distinct` in them.  If you wanted duplicates to be counted separated (so, say, "100, 100, 200, 300" would give you "200" rather than "300"), then use `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using Row_Number()

```
SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score ASC) AS RowNumber,
          *
          FROM student
     ) AS foo
    WHERE RowNumber = 3
```

or you can do it using OFFSET also

```
SELECT score FROM table ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution could be the following
In this case it will give you the nth highest Quantity.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Quantity FROM (
SELECT TOP N Quantity FROM [Order Details] 
ORDER BY Quantity DESC ) temp
ORDER BY Quantity
```

If you want to list all the records who have nth highest then you can use the following

```
SELECT * FROM [Order Details] WHERE Quantity IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 Quantity FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10 Quantity FROM [Order Details] 
    ORDER BY Quantity DESC ) temp
    ORDER BY Quantity)
```

You can change the table and column name as per your need